# Logical / Virtual data store in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is there any way for creating Logical / Virtual data store in HDFS ?

Say I want to create Catagory for Product. so if I query on product hadoop will go for product catagory not for perticular HDFS.

So i want to query based on catagories.

Comment: Question is not clear. please elaborate

Comment: Ok so just thing that we have 2 different cluster and say first cluster have hdfs table for toothbrush and the second one have table for toothpaste. so I want to make out some analysis on these tables. so I thought if there is any way to create an logical/virtual data store on which I can just fire query and get the result....

Comment: What do you mean by **hdfs tables**??hdfs is a **FS** and stores data as files. Also, how are you planning to operate on data stored in 2 different clusters simultaneously?

Comment: sorry my fault, Two imported table into HDFS(FS) and that what I want to know is there any way to create logical or virtual datastore so that I can operate on data.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Hive](http://hive.apache.org). It feel you can achieve this through Hive and it'l be more convenient. Hive provides us warehousing capabilities on top of a running Hadoop cluster. Create a DB for a particular product and store all the data related to that product into tables of this DB. Not just this, Hive also provides us a SQL like interface to the data stored in this warehouse which enables us to query the data of interest directly by writing simple queries without having to write complex MR jobs or lengthy programs.

HTH